# Iframe always showing scroll bars in IE7

Tags: iframe, scroll, internet-explorer-7

Having an annoying issue in IE7. I have a website where, at the bottom of every page theres an Iframe, and for the life of me I cannot get the scroll bars to hide. This is only in IE7, every other browser I have tested is fine.

I have scrolling="no" and set overflow:hidden; still not working though.

If anyones got anything they could suggest I'd be very greatful

http://www.keyscape.co.uk is the site

Cheers
Martin

Comment: see here, i think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354/dreaded-iframe-horizontal-scroll-bar-cant-be-removed-in-ie

Answer (score 17):

adding scroll="no" to the body of my iframe target page worked for me. In total, here's the additional cruft I've added to my iframe for various browsers, perhaps this will help someone else:

iFrame source HTML:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;" scroll="no">
```

iFrame tag on page:

```
<iframe width="280" height="196" src="http://dev.example.com/source.html"
style="overflow:hidden;" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try setting the `BODY` tag of the IFRAME content to `<BODY scroll="no">` and add the following CSS the content's page:

```
html 
{ 
     overflow:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Another thing I've done in the past is set the width and height of the content in the IFRAME and use absolute position.  Try that as well.

Comment: the body thing is important to note

Answer (score 2):

By using jQuery from parent page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#iframeid').contents().find('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
$('#iframeid').contents().find('body').attr('scrolling', 'No');
</script>
```

Use this, it should work.

Comment: This won't work if the page you're iframing is on a different domain (security reasons)