# Remove scroll bars from iFrames in IE8

Tags: jquery

I am using the following jQuery line in order to remove scroll bars from iFrames on a web page:

```
$("iframe").css("overflow", "hidden").attr("scrolling", "no");
```

This works in Chrome and FF but not in IE8.

Any ideas what would require to make it work there?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
iframe {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2898403/iframe-always-showing-scroll-bars-in-ie7

Comment: that's exactly what I am talking about in my answer

Comment: Yes, but I don't have access to change the actual source of the html, I can only hack it using jQuery for various reasons

Comment: Actually that thread you mentioned also have it in jQuery and I think it solved it for me as I'm not using any cross domain code there, thanks

Comment: Well, it solved it for IE8 but introduced it for Chrome now! :) So, a combination of my line and the other lines seem to solve it for both browsers

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about not IFRAME's scrollbars, but about inner HTML. Remove scrollbars from html and body elements in the HTML you display in IFRAME as well, e.g.:

```
$($("iframe")[0].contentDocument).find("html,body").css("overflow","hidden");
```

Comment: I'm talking about an iFrame in an html page and the suggestion above doesn't work unfortunately