# Scrolling=no! does not hide the scroll

Tags: html, css

According the "validator w3c", the scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. It means that for iFrame there is a Scrolling="no" CSS equivalent.

I have tried:
`Overflow: hidden;` but without success.

Here an example with:

[1)Scrolling="no" (it works fine)](http://computerone.altervista.org/iframe_scrolling_no.php)

but w3c it does complain

[2)Scrolling="no" CSS equivalent, (it doesn't work because it shows the scroll)](http://computerone.altervista.org/iframe_scrolling_no_css_equivalent.php)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why such concern over the W3 validator results?

Comment: @anton you should go back to your profile and look at past questions you have asked and click the green question mark next to the correct answers. This allows people who have worked to help you to be rewarded.

Comment: overflow:hidden example works in FF 3.6; which browser doesn't work?

Comment: @oblig IE, of course. It's always IE. -bashes face into keyboard-

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354/dreaded-iframe-horizontal-scroll-bar-cant-be-removed-in-ie

Comment: Actually, I looked at Chrome, IE9, Opera, Safari. Scroll appears in all of them. FF is the odd one out that doesn't show a scroll.

Comment: @zxt IE9 is not a dominant browser yet. IE6, IE7, IE8 are more important. IE7 and IE8 both have the OP's problem as described.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't be bothered to check browsers that I don't have installed. Also, I'm saying I _do_ see a problem in all those other browsers, so no finger pointing at just IE here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scroll: 'no'
```

Is not a valid CSS attribute.

IE is known to have problems with iFrames and the CSS overflow attribute.

- Check out this page for a workaround : http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3113793.htm
- Or this one : http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=107457

Really, the best solution here is to use `scrolling="no"` inside of your iFrame tag. It's true that it doesn't meet the W3 standards - but no customer is going to run away from your site because it has W3 standards problems. The average person has no idea what a web standard even is, let alone W3.

Comment: @zxt metioned this: `Actually, I looked at Chrome, IE9, Opera, Safari. Scroll appears in all of them. FF is the odd one out that doesn't show a scroll`.

Answer (score 1):

below javascript worked for me in FF,chrome and IE

```
var el = document.getElementById("iframeid")
el.scrolling = "no"; //FF & Chrome
el.contentWindow.document.documentElement.style.overflow="hidden"; //IE
```