# iFrame overflow-x BUG on Chrome, IE, Opera, Safari but not on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have to load a remote url in a iFrame. The remote content will be a bit wider than the iFrame. I don't want the horizontal scrollbar to show, but the vertical one if needed.

I tried this following code:

```
<iframe scrolling="auto" style="width:500px; height:300px; border:0; padding:0; margin:0; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;" src="http://digg.com"></iframe>
```

It works on Firefox, but doesn't on IE, Chrome, Opera... it might be a bug or something.
Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DpbUy/3/

---

I also tried the tags `horizontalscrolling` and `horizontalscrolling` of the iFrame provided in the answer marked as accepted in [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67354/dreaded-iframe-horizontal-scroll-bar-cant-be-removed-in-ie), but no luck either.

```
<iframe scrolling="yes" horizontalscrolling="no" verticalscrolling="yes" style="width:500px; height:300px; border:0; padding:0; margin:0;" src="http://digg.com"></iframe>
```

Th doesn't work at all in any browser.

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/85q4r/

---

I know I can just remove the scrollbars of the iFrame and set its height to `4000px` or something, then put it inside of a div with `overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:auto;`, but I want a more clean way.

---

I'm wondering if I just should give up on this and try another approach. Could anybody tell me if it is possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

To remove the horizontal scrollbar from the iframe, apply this css rule to it:

```
iframe{
    overflow-x:hidden
}
```

You don't need to apply it to the iframe content.